# How to create a new array(C) that multiplies a number with a 2d array(D) an then adds a second array(B)?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

The final array C is wrong because when you make the calcs by hand the results are different.

```
Array D={3,0,0}{0,3,0}{0,0,3}
Array B={1,1,1}{2,2,2}{3,3,3}
N=3
```

I have tried seperating the 2 caclulations tha are needed but still get a wrong result.

```
for(row=0;row<N;row++)
    {
        for(col=0;col<N;col++)
        {
                C[row][col]=2*(D[row][col])+3*(B[row][col]);
        }

    }
```

Actual Results are `C={2293184c,2293184c,2293184c}` in every row
Final array C should look like this `C={9,3,3}{6,12,6}{9,9,15}`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: programming language is C